# How to replace values in dictionary where the are multiple trees?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

How can i enter different values to "value1", "value2", "value3" and "value4" when my dictionary is built like the one in the example?

```
{'x':{'xx1':{'xxx1':"value1",'xxx2':"value2"},'xx2':{'xxx1':"value3",'xxx2':"value4"}}}
```

I tried [x][xx1][xxx1] = "new_value1" but this gave this "new_value1" to both "value1" and "value3".

Comment: That's not even a correct piece of Python dictionary

Comment: Nah, it works. If changing a value for a key also changed another value then you probably have lists (or objects of another mutable type) as values, and somehow assigned two references to the same object in two different places

Answer (score 0):

Assign the dictionary to a variable and try the same thing. For eg. assign the dictionary to variable a and do a['x']['xx1']['xxx1'] ='new_value1'